# Mark tableview cell as completed when user user returns from subview

Tags: uitableview, viewwillappear

I am writing an application that teaches a user in lessons separated by sections. I have a tableview filled with custom tableview cells that have a check mark I want to unhide when the user completes the lesson and the lesson view is popped back to the table. Is there a way as my ViewWillAppear is called I can unhide the checkmark label in the specific tableview cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually store my information in an `NSDictionary`. In your case, when the user loads the lesson, you can add a BOOL value to an NSDictionary which will mean the lesson is complete, then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate, add this:

```
if([plistDict objectForKey:@"kComplete"] == YES){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}else{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```